# Gateway 502 errors on swapping

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am getting a pretty inexplicable issue when swapping an app service. It only recently started doing this and it is rather strange.

Essentially the production/staging slot works, doing the 1st phase of swap works. However as soon as I do the complete swap the app becomes unresponsive and eventually returns a gateway error 502 forcing me to swap back.

This is the first time this has ever been an issue (5+ years)

Comment: is it happening on all routes? do you use async in the route that is giving the error?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking question! You may look into ‘Diagnose & Solve problems’ blade to see what happened during swap operation and what caused it to fail. Click on “Check Swap Operations” this will open a page showing all the swaps performed on the Web app and their results and  includes possible root causes for the failures and recommendations on how to fix them.

[Screenshots of the above steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XIok.png)

Comment: For me it just says "No swap operations detected in this timeframe" which really doesn't help